# How to setup Git Extensions & VS2005

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, git-extensions

I have to use VS2005 to modify an old software. I would like to use Git in order to create a new repository for the project, but unfortunatelly I'm new to Git, this is an opportunity to me to learn something about that.

I read I have to use Git Extensions if I want to work with VS2005 and I installed it, I have already installed Git.

Now inside VS2005 I don't find anything about Git or Git Extensions (no toolbar commands or menu options) and I don't know what I have to do.

Unfortunatelly I don't find anything about the interaction with VS2005.

Any idea about the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to use VS2005 to modify an old software. I would like to use Git in order to create a new repository for the project,

Very clever move.

> I read I have to use Git Extensions if I want to work with VS2005

Not necessary. Nothing will bring you git integration in VS2005. But you could use every git GUI you want outside VS, which is perfectly fine. GitExtensions is indeed a very good GUI.

> Unfortunatelly I don't find anything about the interaction with VS2005.

GitExtensions is not compatible with VS20015 ( See https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/#downloads ).

But that's not a big problem because Git is not linked to an IDE and you could perfectly do all the git stuff from outside VS (and I also advise to do it that way!).

Open GitExtensions and [create your repository](https://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#create-new-repository).

Then do everything from inside GitExtensions.

For a personal point of view, that's the way I use it for years because even in recent version of VS, the git integration is not perfect and sometimes could be confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the support Philippe, I did it and everything works good. Probably in this way is a little bit tricky, because this is my first time with Git. Can you suggest me a good guide?

Comment: @Scarj Most of the training you will find is for command line but should be enough to understand concept. Here is a old list of resources (look especially at the 'tutorial' section)  https://gist.github.com/pmiossec/333645ffd7d71670b731